# React Native - AsyncStorage is null

Tags: ios, react-native, asyncstorage

[image]

I got these errores when I was adding AsyncStorage dependencies (https://github.com/react-native-community/async-storage)

I was using React Native CLI, not expo, I had ran 'react-native link @react-native-community/async-storage' in the project root.

My problem was when i ran '--clearCache' flag, maybe that was my problem, I don't know. If you know how to run the flag '--clearCache' please help me.

Comment: try by running `pod install` inside the /ios directory.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

react-native link @react-native-community/async-storage

Then 
Run react-native run-android

Answer (score 0):

For me, 
 1. Reinstalling app 
2. restarting bundler with `npm start --reset-cache` 
solved the [issue](https://github.com/react-native-async-storage/async-storage/issues/304#issuecomment-748644524)! in Android

Answer (score 0):

I have solve this issue by following steps

- delete your app ( emulator or real device )
- Open project in Xcode
- go to Menu -> product -> clean build folder
- clean derived data

And it's done